# Angular Material Auto Complete Not Setting Selected when Filtered

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I have come across an issue with the mat-autocomplete control for Angular Material where it does not add the CSS class "mdc-list-item--selected" to the mat-option and also doesn't add the mat-pseudo-checkbox to a selected option when the contents are displayed via an observable filtered array.

I've created a stackblitz where you can see the issue.

[Mat-Autocomplete Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/youm9c?file=src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-optgroup-example.html)

The Filtered States Group does not show the selected option with a check and purple text but the Not Filtered States Group does.  The ability for the user to see the selected option is important because they can modify the auto-complete after selecting a value to start a new search, however that doesn't actually change the selected value.  So the visual indications for the selected option is very important for the usability.

[image: Filtered States Group]
[image: Not Filtered States Group]

Does anyone see any issues with how this is configured in the stackblitz link or know of a work around?

I forked this stackblitz from the Angular Material's optgroup example that also has the same issue.

Comment: I've opened the following issue with the Angular Material team as I believe this is a bug.  https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Yurii that responded to the issue that I created in the Angular Github with the following solution:

> As far as I can tell, the problem is not with the OptGroup component; rather, it is with the MatAutoComplete component, which does not handle a selection of selected mat-option like MatSelect does (At least I don't see that code)
>
> The way it works: Each mat-option holds a selected state and emits the
> event that the selection has been made. The MatAutoComplete does not
> listen to those changes and does not manage a selection state.
>
> In the example that you have provided, you are returning a brand-new
> object after the search .map((group) => ({ letter: group.letter,
> names: _filter(group.names, value), }))
>
> This code makes Angular to re-render the list which destroys
> mat-option instances that had the selected flag set to true and that
> is why you don't see the "highlighted" state.
>
> To fix your issue you could use a trackBy function
> *ngFor="let group of stateGroupOptions | async; trackBy: trackByFn"
>
> trackByFn = (_: number, item: StateGroup): string => { return
> item.letter; };